# Error adding entities to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm getting the following exception message:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

And my inner exception is related to me change column names on my table as they didn't make sense before (They were given the name Customer_Customer_ID) and renamed my Sku and my Customer objects that are composed in my cart, with the following data annotations

```
  [Table("Cart")]
    public class Cart
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public Guid CartID { get; set; }

        [Column("SkuID")]
        public virtual Sku Sku { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Column("CustomerID")]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public bool IsCheckedOut { get; set; }



    }
```

This is the inner exception of the exception message

> "Invalid column name 'Customer_Customer_ID'.\r\nInvalid column name
>   'Sku_SKU_ID'."

What is the correct way to name these composed objects and do I need to modify my OnModelCreating to reflect these changes to entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `SkuID` and `CustomerId` property to your entity class.

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Guid CartID { get; set; }

    public int SkuID { set;get;}

    public virtual Sku Sku { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID{ set;get;}

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public bool IsCheckedOut { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming your Sku and Customer class has an ID property of type `int` and it is the primary key. EF will create Cart table with foreign keys to `Sku` and `Customer` table(s) properly because the current structure follow the convention.

Now your entity class has both integer Id (`CustomerID`) and the navigation property (`Customer`)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that that made a difference. Do I need to add data annotations that they are foreign keys?

Comment: No need to add data annotation as you are following the convention (Your column name is TableName+"ID" (Ex:CustomerId)

Comment: When I try to run the migration, it still outputs Customer_CustomerID and my regular customer ID. How do I avoid the Customer_CustomerID. I copied exactly what you have.

Comment: You are getting an error (code crashing to an exception ?) with the above code ?

Comment: I believe the issue was your assumption was incorrect on my end. I renamed the properties to ID from Customer_ID and it is naming them as I want in the database now.